# Is it possible to install a django package without pip?

Tags: django, installation

I am trying to install django-dash to run one of the dashboard examples and see what it's like.

I am on Windows running Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.5. I know the usual approach is to download pip then install the package using pip. However, I am on a work computer with no administrative rights so I can't access my Internet Option Settings to find my proxy URL to follow the instructions below:

```
Proxy problems

If you work in an office, you might be behind a HTTP proxy. If so, set the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy. Most Python applications (and other free software) respect these. Example syntax:
http://proxy_url:port
http://username:password@proxy_url:port
```

I had the same issue when trying to install Django but was able to get it to work by moving the django directory under Python27/Lib/site-packages. Is there something similar I can do with django-dash?

I also tried downloading the sources and running python setup.py install. I received the following error:

```
File "setup.py", line 3, in <module> from setuptools import setup, find_packages ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Link to django-dash: http://django-dash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can probably get the sources from [The Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/)

Once you have them, uncompress the files and install them manually (this will depend on you OS).

On Linux systems:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Here's [the full reference](https://docs.python.org/2/install/)

**EDIT :** Note that when manually installing those packages, you must also install any missing dependencies, eg. setuptools in your case

Comment: I did download the sources before and tried python setup.py install and received the following error: File "setup.py", line 3, in <module> from setuptools import setup, find_packages, ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: Post the full error, I can't see what the problem is with that message, but I guess you miss a dependence

Comment: Full error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "setup.py", line 3, in <module> from setuptools import setup, find_packages, ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: Then you must install setuptools too

Comment: Yeah, haha I tried that right after rereading the error. I was afraid I would have problems installing setuptools just like pip but it seems to be working. Thanks! Will mark up