# Installing django-dash - Download error, could not find suitable distribution for [multiple packages]

Tags: django, installation

Related to my question here: [Is it possible to install a django package without pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512320/is-it-possible-to-install-a-django-package-without-pip/24512446?noredirect=1#comment37950547_24512446)

I am on a Windows work computer, no administrative rights, manually installing packages for Django. I am trying to install django-dash with little luck. After running python setup.py install for django-dash, I get an error that looks like:

```
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple: timed out - Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pillow
```

I had the same error for localeurl-1.2.0, vishap-0.1.1, etc. Sometimes those packages would have missing dependencies as well and I would manually install those. I do not know how many dependencies are missing still as it only shows one error at a time. Is this common with Django packages, is it a security issue, or did I do something wrong when downloading django-dash?

Comment: how are you actually installing any package?? I mean what you mean by manual method. thanks

Comment: I am just looking up the package ex localeurl on pypi.python.org, downloading the zip folder, extracting and then running python setup.py install on it. Not sure if that's really called manual, that's what I'm calling it since all the dependencies are supposed to be automatically installed as well, instead of me looking for them separately.. After I downloaded localeurl for example, I went back and ran python setup.py install on django-dash again and got a new error on how vishap download files could not be found. I went to download vishap files, and installed, then ran django-dash again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to try to find a `requirements.txt` in github/bitbucket repository of `django_dash` and download/install those packages written in the `requirements.txt`. There is always a requirement.txt in pip package's source(in repo) where dependencies are written. `pip` installs those requirements by itself so its no hassle for pip users. Since you can't use pip, you have to install those requirements manually(the method you mentioned in comments). By the way, here is `django dash`'s requirement file: https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-dash/blob/master/example/requirements.txt

Comment: I see, guess the list is better than I imagined. I'll try that out. Thanks!